# Add JSON to Parse.Cloud.httpRequest "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, stripe-connect

I've been trying to implement Stripe's Managed Accounts into my cloud code functions.
I managed to make it work so far but now I have ran into a problem which I can't seem to solve.

What it comes down to:
    Using `'content_type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` how can I send a JSON?

It's not possible to change the content_type to `application/JSON` since Stripe expects a form-urlencoded.
I tried to stringify the JSON, but Stripe also complains when I do this. It expects a 'hash', which I assume is a JSON.

Is it possible to url encode a JSON so I can send it while still having the content_type set to form-urlencoded?

My current code does not work since Parse says:

> Uncaught Error: Can't form encode an Object

```
var secret_key = stripeKeys.stripeSecretKey;
var cardTokenId = "tok_...";
var country = "BE";
var currency = "EUR";
var email = "test@test.org";
var firstName = "test";
var lastName = "tester";
var dobDay = 1;
var dobMonth = 1;
var dobYear = 1950;
var addressCity = "City";
var addressCountry = "Country";
var addressLine = "Address line";
var addressZIP = "ZIP";
var addressProvince = "Province";
```

---

```
var createAccountPromise = function()
{
    var params = 
        {
            url: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts",
            method: "POST",
            headers: 
            {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer(secret_key + ":").toString("base64"),
                "content_type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            body: 
            {   
                "country": country,
                "default_currency": currency,
                "email": email,
                "managed": true,
                "legal_entity":
                    {
                        "first_name": firstName,
                        "last_name": lastName,
                        "type": "individual",
                        "dob":
                            {
                                "day": dobDay,
                                "month": dobMonth,
                                "year": dobYear
                            },
                        "personal_address":
                            {
                                "city": addressCity,
                                "country": addressCountry,
                                "line1": addressLine,
                                "postal_code": addressZIP,
                                "state": addressProvince
                            }
                    },
                "external_account": cardTokenId
            }
        };
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params);
}
```

---

```
createAccountPromise()
    .then(function(result)
    {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + result.text);
        response.success("Account Created");
    },
    function(errorReason)
    {
        console.log("ERROR: " + errorReason.text);
        response.error("Account NOT Created because: " + errorReason.text);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type results in a "flat" `key=value` list of attributes, while you are passing a hierarchical object with multiple levels. JSON knows how to encode such an object, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not (there are several different ways of doing this, with dot notation, brackets, etc.).

What you should do is "flatten" your JSON object so that it only has one level, and use the "expanded" names as keys. I.e. instead of having a `legal_entity` that contains a `first_name`, directly set `legal_entity[first_name]` (to match the format used by Stripe).

So, your body would be:

```
body: 
{   
    "country": country,
    "default_currency": currency,
    "email": email,
    "managed": true,
    "legal_entity[first_name]": firstName,
    "legal_entity[last_name]": lastName,
    "legal_entity[type]": "individual",
    "legal_entity[dob][day]": dobDay,
    "legal_entity[dob][month]": dobMonth,
    "legal_entity[dob][year]": dobYear
    "legal_entity[personal_address][city]": addressCity,
    "legal_entity[personal_address][country]": addressCountry,
    "legal_entity[personal_address][line1]": addressLine,
    "legal_entity[personal_address][postal_code]": addressZIP,
    "legal_entity[personal_address][state]": addressProvince
    "external_account": cardTokenId
}
```

Of course, if you have more complex objects, it's possible to "flatten" things in code rather than do it manually.

Also, you should use `Content-Type`, not `content_type`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It works :) although the content_type or Content-type thing does not really matter, I tried both and they both work

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to convert json to x-www-form-urlencoded. Then send request.

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(encodeURIComponent(params));
```

Or

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params)));
```

Comment: This gives me the error: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: It may be because of one or more of params object properties are undefined. Please check all values of params object when calling function.

Comment: I updated the code, tell me what you need and I'll provide it :)

Comment: please add this line to your code. console.log(JSON.stringify(params, null, 4)) before return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(params); then run code and send output please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100388/discussion-between-gor-and-thetool).